# Can any one explain how the control flow in this following Treeviewer code?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

The program works fine but I am not able to see how it all links together.  I mean, I don't call the methods in the class extended by Icontent provider or Ilabel Provider; how is it getting called?

I copied the code from http://java2s.com/.

```
package com.test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProviderListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProviderChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;


/**
 * This class demonstrates TreeViewer. It shows the drives, directories, and
 * files on the system.
 */
public class FileTree extends ApplicationWindow {
  /**
   * FileTree constructor
   */
  public FileTree() {
    super(null);
  }

  /**
   * Runs the application
   */
  public void run() {
    // Don't return from open() until window closes
    setBlockOnOpen(true);

    // Open the main window
    open();

    // Dispose the display
    Display.getCurrent().dispose();
  }

  /**
   * Configures the shell
   * 
   * @param shell
   *            the shell
   */
  protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
    super.configureShell(shell);

    // Set the title bar text and the size
    shell.setText("File Tree");
    shell.setSize(400, 400);
  }

  /**
   * Creates the main window's contents
   * 
   * @param parent
   *            the main window
   * @return Control
   */
  protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    // Add a checkbox to toggle whether the labels preserve case
    Button preserveCase = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
    preserveCase.setText("&Preserve case");

    // Create the tree viewer to display the file tree
    final TreeViewer tv = new TreeViewer(composite);
    tv.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
    tv.setContentProvider(new FileTreeContentProvider());
    tv.setLabelProvider(new FileTreeLabelProvider());
    tv.setInput("root"); // pass a non-null that will be ignored

    // When user checks the checkbox, toggle the preserve case attribute
    // of the label provider
    preserveCase.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
        boolean preserveCase = ((Button) event.widget).getSelection();
        FileTreeLabelProvider ftlp = (FileTreeLabelProvider) tv
            .getLabelProvider();
        ftlp.setPreserveCase(preserveCase);
      }
    });
    return composite;
  }

  /**
   * The application entry point
   * 
   * @param args
   *            the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new FileTree().run();
  }
}

/**
 * This class provides the content for the tree in FileTree
 */

class FileTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {
  /**
   * Gets the children of the specified object
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the parent object
   * @return Object[]
   */
  public Object[] getChildren(Object arg0) {
    // Return the files and subdirectories in this directory
    return ((File) arg0).listFiles();
  }

  /**
   * Gets the parent of the specified object
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the object
   * @return Object
   */
  public Object getParent(Object arg0) {
    // Return this file's parent file
    return ((File) arg0).getParentFile();
  }

  /**
   * Returns whether the passed object has children
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the parent object
   * @return boolean
   */
  public boolean hasChildren(Object arg0) {
    // Get the children
    Object[] obj = getChildren(arg0);

    // Return whether the parent has children
    return obj == null ? false : obj.length > 0;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the root element(s) of the tree
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the input data
   * @return Object[]
   */
  public Object[] getElements(Object arg0) {
    // These are the root elements of the tree
    // We don't care what arg0 is, because we just want all
    // the root nodes in the file system
    return File.listRoots();
  }

  /**
   * Disposes any created resources
   */
  public void dispose() {
    // Nothing to dispose
  }

  /**
   * Called when the input changes
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the viewer
   * @param arg1
   *            the old input
   * @param arg2
   *            the new input
   */
  public void inputChanged(Viewer arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
    // Nothing to change
  }
}

/**
 * This class provides the labels for the file tree
 */

class FileTreeLabelProvider implements ILabelProvider {
  // The listeners
  private List listeners;

  // Images for tree nodes
  private Image file;

  private Image dir;

  // Label provider state: preserve case of file names/directories
  boolean preserveCase;

  /**
   * Constructs a FileTreeLabelProvider
   */
  public FileTreeLabelProvider() {
    // Create the list to hold the listeners
    listeners = new ArrayList();

    // Create the images
    try {
      file = new Image(null, new FileInputStream("images/file.gif"));
      dir = new Image(null, new FileInputStream("images/directory.gif"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // Swallow it; we'll do without images
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sets the preserve case attribute
   * 
   * @param preserveCase
   *            the preserve case attribute
   */
  public void setPreserveCase(boolean preserveCase) {
    this.preserveCase = preserveCase;

    // Since this attribute affects how the labels are computed,
    // notify all the listeners of the change.
    LabelProviderChangedEvent event = new LabelProviderChangedEvent(this);
    for (int i = 0, n = listeners.size(); i < n; i++) {
      ILabelProviderListener ilpl = (ILabelProviderListener) listeners
          .get(i);
      ilpl.labelProviderChanged(event);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the image to display for a node in the tree
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the node
   * @return Image
   */
  public Image getImage(Object arg0) {
    // If the node represents a directory, return the directory image.
    // Otherwise, return the file image.
    return ((File) arg0).isDirectory() ? dir : file;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the text to display for a node in the tree
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the node
   * @return String
   */
  public String getText(Object arg0) {
    // Get the name of the file
    String text = ((File) arg0).getName();

    // If name is blank, get the path
    if (text.length() == 0) {
      text = ((File) arg0).getPath();
    }

    // Check the case settings before returning the text
    return preserveCase ? text : text.toUpperCase();
  }

  /**
   * Adds a listener to this label provider
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the listener
   */
  public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
    listeners.add(arg0);
  }

  /**
   * Called when this LabelProvider is being disposed
   */
  public void dispose() {
    // Dispose the images
    if (dir != null)
      dir.dispose();
    if (file != null)
      file.dispose();
  }

  /**
   * Returns whether changes to the specified property on the specified
   * element would affect the label for the element
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the element
   * @param arg1
   *            the property
   * @return boolean
   */
  public boolean isLabelProperty(Object arg0, String arg1) {
    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Removes the listener
   * 
   * @param arg0
   *            the listener to remove
   */
  public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
    listeners.remove(arg0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines here...

```
tv.setContentProvider(new FileTreeContentProvider());
tv.setLabelProvider(new FileTreeLabelProvider());
```

...are setting the classes in your code on the TreeViewer component.

The TreeViewer will call the methods you've provided to create the tree contents and the labels.

If you want to see the exact flow you should set a breakpoint on one of the methods and run under the debugger.  You will then be able to see the call stack when the method is called.